# changing jQ ui-accordion-content with another style css

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I've been fooling with this for awhile and must be missing a fact.
I have a table inside an accordion. The table has trows and tdata.

```
<tr class='edit'>
```

and it picks up

```
ui-widget-content{ color:#99cc33; }
```

(ie. firebug)

Since I only want to change the row color, not the rest of the widget content.

```
<tr class='edit table-data'>
```

and set

```
.table-data{ color:#cccccc; }
```

This I thought would work ???

```
class='edit'
```

is a

```
$('form').on( { mouseenter: function() { ...
```

that works fine so I've commented out to keep it simple.

Would someone please enlighten me, thanks in advance.

```
.edit.table-data{ color:#cccccc; } fails
```

and as mentioned in comment below I'm trying to change the css befor it reaches the
client. $('form').on() changes color with client movements just fine.

SOLVED- an error in css .edit The lesson here appears that incorrect css is not "ignored entirely". For example

```
 <tr class='edit data'>
```

.data though correct will not work if .edit fails. (at least using jQuery)

Comment: I should have added this earlier... sorry. <tr class='edit' style='{color:#cccccc;}'> works as expected. Putting .table-data{color:#cccccc;} into style sheet is whats failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'll need to use CSS specificity to return the table contents to the original color:

```
.table-data { color:#cccccc; }
.table-data .other-stuff { color: #000; }
```

Comment: what do you mean .other-stuff? I'm trying to change the css before the client sees it. The .on() changes it based on client movements and works fine.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood. Feel free to edit your original post to include what you mentioned in your comment. 

Your original code should work. There must be more to the scenario than we're reading here.